# Getting a view outside the project in razor application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, dll

I have added a `dll` to my application. it is the Dll generated by an asp.net web application mvc `MyCalendar`.

I'd like to acces to a view inside this dll , i added this snippet:

```
    namespace MvcApplication10.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            //
            // GET: /Home/

            public ActionResult Index()
            {                    
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyCalendar.Controllers.Calendar", null);                   
            }

        }
    }
```

But it didn't work. So what is the reason of this failure? How can i call a view outside my project?

Comment: I made this with MEF: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/04/21/ASPNET-MVC-and-the-Managed-Extensibility-Framework-%28MEF%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller name field just pass controller name instead of whole namespace of the controller.

you can pass like below:

```
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Calendar");
```

Syntax is

```
 RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");
```